# symfony server:start command throwing an error

Tags: bash, symfony, symfony4

I try to run

```
symfony server:start
```

It returns an error message

```
The local web server is already running for this project at port 8000
```

But `lsof -wni tcp:8000` isn't returning anything, I'm sure there isn't any softwares using the port 8000.

Starting by doing

```
bin/console server:start
```

is working like a charm.

Comment: A reboot should definitely shutdown the offending culprit.  Assuming symfony server:start used to work.

Comment: It does it even after a reboot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`symfony server:start` writes a pid file to `~/.symfony/var/`.

Remove the correct pid file (i.e the one that references the current project dir)

Comment: Where is `~/.symfony/var/` ?

Comment: i answer to myself : `C:\Users\<YourName>\.symfony`

Comment: Indeed: under Linux distributions, the `~/` folder is an alias to the user's personal folder, which translates to `C:\Users\<YourName>` under Windows

Answer (score 3):

You can make a

```
symfony server:stop
```

The system reboot and symfony serve will works again.